# Pure-Python inverse error function

Tags: python, math, scipy

Are there any **pure-python** implementations of the inverse error function?

I know that SciPy has [scipy.special.erfinv()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.erfinv.html), but that relies on some C extensions. I'd like a pure python implementation.

I've tried writing my own using the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Inverse_functions) and [Wolfram](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseErf/) references, but it always seems to diverge from the true value when the arg is > 0.9.

I've also attempted to port the underlying C code that Scipy uses ([`ndtri.c`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/cephes/ndtri.c) and the [cephes `polevl.c`](https://github.com/jeremybarnes/cephes/blob/master/cprob/polevl.c) functions) but that's also not passing my unit tests.

---

Edit: As requested, I've added the ported code.

Docstrings (and doctests) have been removed because they're longer than the functions. I haven't yet put much effort into making the port more pythonic - I'll worry about that once I get something that passes unit tests.

#### Supporting functions from [cephes `polevl.c`](https://github.com/jeremybarnes/cephes/blob/master/cprob/polevl.c)

```
def polevl(x, coefs, N):
    ans = 0
    power = len(coefs) - 1
    for coef in coefs[:N]:
        ans += coef * x**power
        power -= 1

    return ans

def p1evl(x, coefs, N):
    return polevl(x, [1] + coefs, N)
```

#### Main Inverse Error Function

```
def inv_erf(z):
    if z < -1 or z > 1:
        raise ValueError("`z` must be between -1 and 1 inclusive")

    if z == 0:
        return 0
    if z == 1:
        return math.inf
    if z == -1:
        return -math.inf

    # From scipy special/cephes/ndrti.c
    def ndtri(y):
        # approximation for 0 <= abs(z - 0.5) <= 3/8
        P0 = [
            -5.99633501014107895267E1,
            9.80010754185999661536E1,
            -5.66762857469070293439E1,
            1.39312609387279679503E1,
            -1.23916583867381258016E0,
        ]

        Q0 = [
            1.95448858338141759834E0,
            4.67627912898881538453E0,
            8.63602421390890590575E1,
            -2.25462687854119370527E2,
            2.00260212380060660359E2,
            -8.20372256168333339912E1,
            1.59056225126211695515E1,
            -1.18331621121330003142E0,
        ]

        # Approximation for interval z = sqrt(-2 log y ) between 2 and 8
        # i.e., y between exp(-2) = .135 and exp(-32) = 1.27e-14.
        P1 = [
            4.05544892305962419923E0,
            3.15251094599893866154E1,
            5.71628192246421288162E1,
            4.40805073893200834700E1,
            1.46849561928858024014E1,
            2.18663306850790267539E0,
            -1.40256079171354495875E-1,
            -3.50424626827848203418E-2,
            -8.57456785154685413611E-4,
        ]

        Q1 = [
            1.57799883256466749731E1,
            4.53907635128879210584E1,
            4.13172038254672030440E1,
            1.50425385692907503408E1,
            2.50464946208309415979E0,
            -1.42182922854787788574E-1,
            -3.80806407691578277194E-2,
            -9.33259480895457427372E-4,
        ]

        # Approximation for interval z = sqrt(-2 log y ) between 8 and 64
        # i.e., y between exp(-32) = 1.27e-14 and exp(-2048) = 3.67e-890.
        P2 = [
            3.23774891776946035970E0,
            6.91522889068984211695E0,
            3.93881025292474443415E0,
            1.33303460815807542389E0,
            2.01485389549179081538E-1,
            1.23716634817820021358E-2,
            3.01581553508235416007E-4,
            2.65806974686737550832E-6,
            6.23974539184983293730E-9,
        ]

        Q2 = [
            6.02427039364742014255E0,
            3.67983563856160859403E0,
            1.37702099489081330271E0,
            2.16236993594496635890E-1,
            1.34204006088543189037E-2,
            3.28014464682127739104E-4,
            2.89247864745380683936E-6,
            6.79019408009981274425E-9,
        ]

        s2pi = 2.50662827463100050242
        code = 1

        if y > (1.0 - 0.13533528323661269189):      # 0.135... = exp(-2)
            y = 1.0 - y
            code = 0

        if y > 0.13533528323661269189:
            y = y - 0.5
            y2 = y * y
            x = y + y * (y2 * polevl(y2, P0, 4) / p1evl(y2, Q0, 8))
            x = x * s2pi
            return x

        x = math.sqrt(-2.0 * math.log(y))
        x0 = x - math.log(x) / x

        z = 1.0 / x
        if x < 8.0:                 # y > exp(-32) = 1.2664165549e-14
            x1 = z * polevl(z, P1, 8) / p1evl(z, Q1, 8)
        else:
            x1 = z * polevl(z, P2, 8) / p1evl(z, Q2, 8)

        x = x0 - x1
        if code != 0:
            x = -x

        return x

    result = ndtri((z + 1) / 2.0) / math.sqrt(2)

    return result
```

Comment: Post your ported code, it doesn't look like it would be long.

Comment: @Blender Done, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the error in your code is in the for loop over coefficients in the polevl function. If you replace what you have with the function below everything seems to work.

```
def polevl(x, coefs, N):
    ans = 0
    power = len(coefs) - 1
    for coef in coefs:
        ans += coef * x**power
        power -= 1
    return ans
```

I have tested it against scipy's implementation with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erfinv
N = 100000
x = np.random.rand(N) - 1.

# Calculate the inverse of the error function
y = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    y[i] = inv_erf(x[i])

assert np.allclose(y, erfinv(x))
```

Comment: Yes it looks like that was it! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Nice catch. I was thinking it was some compiler optimizations, but this is much simpler...

Comment: I get below error:
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
in engine
----> 1 df1 = df.withColumn('prob', inv_erf(F.col('value')))

<ipython-input-1-1a0012c36367> in inv_erf(z)
      1 def inv_erf(z):
----> 2     if z < -1 or z > 1:

Comment: @amy: It looks like your passing an array of values using a Pandas dataframe. This does not work because Dthor’s code only works on a single element at a time.

Answer (score 1):

sympy? some digging may be needed to see how its implemented internally  http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#sympy.functions.special.error_functions.erfinv

```
from sympy import erfinv
erfinv(0.9).evalf(30)
1.16308715367667425688580351562
```