# Pyspark - erfinv function is not working properly

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Please find the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import math
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from scipy.special import erfinv


# create sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 0.008),
    (2, -1.23),
    (3, 4.56),
], ['id', 'value'])

def normal_cdf(x):

    return (math.sqrt(2) * erfinv(x*2-1))
  
my_udf1 = udf(normal_cdf)

df1 = df.withColumn('prob', my_udf1(F.col('value')))

df1.show()
```

Error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o420.showString. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3
> in stage 6.0 (TID 21, d2-td-cdh.boigroup.net, executor 17):
> org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 361, in main
> func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)   File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 236, in read_udfs
> arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)   File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 163, in read_single_udf
> f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)   File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 64, in read_command
> command = serializer._read_with_length(file)   File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 172, in _read_with_length
> return self.loads(obj)   File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 577, in loads
> return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line
> 131, in _ufunc_reconstruct
> mod = **import**(module, fromlist=[name]) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

It works fine when executed separately:

```
n=math.sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*0.010-1)
print(n)
```

I have Scipy on my system.
What is the issue here?

Comment: Do you have installed scipy on all worker nodes (and not only on the driver node)?

Comment: I have Scipy on my cdsw (I guess worker node)..how do I check for driver node?

Comment: I would try to ssh into the different nodes. But I don't know if that is possible in cdsw.

Comment: Is there any lib which provides erfinv function apart from scipy?

Comment: you could try to implement the function directly [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42381244/2129801)

Answer (score 1):

This is because some dtypes which are being returned by numpy are not compatible with spark, also I think you should replace `np.nan` with `Null`, try below:

```
def normal_cdf(x):
    val = (math.sqrt(2) * erfinv(x*2-1)) 
    return float(val) if pd.notna(val) else None
  
my_udf1 = udf(normal_cdf)
#my_udf1 = udf(normal_cdf,T.DoubleType()) for returning double

df1 = df.withColumn('prob', my_udf1(F.col('value')))
```

---

```
df1.show()

+---+-----+-------------------+
| id|value|               prob|
+---+-----+-------------------+
|  1|0.008|-2.4089155458154616|
|  2|-1.23|               null|
|  3| 4.56|               null|
+---+-----+-------------------+
```

Comment: I still get the same error; Can u please explain why it works on a number and not on a dataframe; 
n=math.sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*0.008-1)
print(n)