# erfinv function not working on a data frame - pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working in cdsw.
Code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 0.008),
    (2, -1.23),
    (3, 4.56),
], ['id', 'value'])

def normal_cdf(x):
    val = (math.sqrt(2) * erfinv(x*2-1)) 
    return float(val)
  
my_udf1 = udf(normal_cdf)
#my_udf1 = udf(normal_cdf,T.DoubleType()) for returning double

df1 = df.withColumn('prob', my_udf1(F.col('value')))
df1.show()
```

Throws error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o293.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 11, d4-td-cdh.boigroup.net, executor 12): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 361, in main
func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 236, in read_udfs
arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 163, in read_single_udf
f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 64, in read_command
command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 577, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 131, in _ufunc_reconstruct
mod = **import**(module, fromlist=[name])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

However,below code works

```
n=math.sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*0.008-1)
print(n)
```

I cannot upgrade due to restrictions.
Any other way to calculate erfinv? function

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42381244/9477843) might be useful for you

Comment: tried the solution : it results in error : ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', 
----> 1 df1 = df.withColumn('prob', inv_erf(F.col('value')))